# Translating Logical Statements

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

S = Grizz is asleep

R = Grizz is hungry

U = Grizz plays fetch

V = Grizz bites Nate

I want to translate the following English sentences below into logical statements, using only symbols ¬, ∧, ∨, and/or ⇒. I am unsure if I have completed these correctly (especially for 1 and 3).

1. Grizz is hungry, or he plays fetch, but never both.

- What I have tried: (R ∧ ¬U) ∨ (¬R ∧ U)

2. Grizz bites Nate if he is hungry or if he plays fetch.

- What I have tried: (R ∨ U) ⇒ V

3. If Grizz is hungry, then he will bite Nate, but if he is not hungry, then if he’s awake he will bite Nate.

- What I have tried: (R ⇒ V) ∨ [¬R ⇒ (¬S ∧ V)]

Answer (score 0):

The first two statements are correct.

In the third statement, notice that you can replace "..but if..." with "...and if..." without changing the meaning, so you should be using the "AND" operator, not the "OR" operator. Furthermore, "IF he's awake, (then) he will bite Nate" should be written with an implication, not with an "AND".

The correct form for the third statement would be

$(R\implies V)\land(\neg R\implies(\neg S \implies V))$

We can simplify this further by using the tautologies of propositional logic

$(R\implies V)\land((\neg R\land\neg S) \implies V)$

$(R\lor(\neg R\land\neg S))\implies V$

$(R\lor\neg S)\implies V$